# Dotmim.Sync SqliteSyncProvider is throwing exception in Xamarin IOS | Offline Sync

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use Dotmim.Sync with my Xamarin IOS project.
I have added a .net standard 2.0 project in my solution. Added Dotmim.Sync.Sqlite & Dotmim.Sync.Web.Client nuggets.
Here is the SyncService code:

```
  public async Task SyncAsync()
  {
     var proxyClientProvider = new WebClientOrchestrator("https://localhost:44358/api/sync");
     var clientProvider = new SqliteSyncProvider("mymobile.db");

     var progress = new SynchronousProgress<ProgressArgs>(s => Console.WriteLine($"{s.Context.SyncStage}:\t{s.Message}"));
     var agent = new SyncAgent(clientProvider, proxyClientProvider);
     do
     {
        // Launch the sync process
        var s1 = await agent.SynchronizeAsync(progress);
        // Write results
        Console.WriteLine(s1);

     } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
     Console.WriteLine("End");
}
```

I have added that .net standard project reference into my iOS project and called the Sync Service class (just for the POC).

```
 mButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
{
    SyncService sync = new SyncService();
    Sync. SyncAsync ();
 };
```

at

```
 var s1 = await agent.SynchronizeAsync(progress);
```

It's throwing an exception:

```
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_open_v2 (SQLitePCL.utf8z filename, SQLitePCL.sqlite3& db, 
  System.Int32 flags, SQLitePCL.utf8z vfs) [0x00000] in <15ecb38d58394d7b88b3f841a7dda078>:0
  at SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_open_v2 (System.String filename, SQLitePCL.sqlite3& db, 
  System.Int32 flags, System.String vfs) [0x0000e] in <15ecb38d58394d7b88b3f841a7dda078>:0
  At Microsoft. Data. Sqlite. SqliteConnection. Open () [0x00122] in 
 <9ffe4c48f3134a7b905b5da527410f26>:0
 at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken 
 cancellationToken) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.8.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/.    System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/Common/DbConnection.cs:122
```

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

And System.Console.ReadKey gives 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

Any suggestion/help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();`

This is part of the Xamarin limitations. More information here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/xamarin

Regarding `Dotmim.Sync`, see more informaition here : https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync/issues/249#issuecomment-609025301